# How to parse span from url source code? using c#

Tags: c#

i have url source code and i need to parse something like this
`<status>Online</status>` how can i parse the in between of these two (ex: Online), i thought about using regex but idk exactly how to do that, thanks in advance.

tried to do substring with index of "example" but the length went too big and couldn't measure that

Comment: Is the overall data in a structured and standard format, such as XML?  If so, can you use any XML parsing tool to read it?

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, if you want to parse the string Online and get the content Online, you can use any of the above options. Here are some code snippets that demonstrate how to do it:

**Using XmlDocument:**

```
using System.Xml;

string xml = "<status>Online</status>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (xml);
string status = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText; // status = "Online"
```

**Using XDocument:**

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

string xml = "<status>Online</status>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse (xml);
string status = doc.Root.Value; // status = "Online"
```

**Using XmlSerializer:**

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot ("status")]
public class Status
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

string xml = "<status>Online</status>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof (Status));
Status status = (Status)serializer.Deserialize (new StringReader (xml)); // status.Value = "Online"
```

Comment: you're welcome, If your problem is solved, please select my answer as the correct answer